# Passing a parameter to objects created by defaultdict

Tags: python, defaultdict

I want to have a default dict that includes a parameter when it constructs a new object. Is this possible, is there a better way to do it?

```
defaultdict(myobj, param1)
```

then myobj:

```
class myobj(object):

    def __init__(self, param1):
        self.param1 = param1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`defaultdict` takes any callable, so you can create a new function that doesn't take a parameter and returns an object instantiated with the parameter you want.

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: myobj(param1))
```

Another option is to use functools.partial, which creates a function with one (or more) of the parameters predefined:

```
import functools
d = defaultdict(functools.partial(myobj, param1))
```

Comment: +1 to JonClements's point. The easiest way to be careful about the scope is to explicitly create the function (/closure) with a `def`, then pass that function to `defaultdict`. Then you've got something you can debug and inspect properly.

Comment: I didn't know lambdas don't have closures. Does anyone know whether `functools.partial` would work better, then?

Comment: `lambda`s and `def`s have the exact same scope rules. `functools.partial` is a good way to avoid the headache if you're doing this in a loop, though.

Comment: Lambdas do have closures (in fact, there's no such thing as "lambdas"; what `lambda` creates is just a function, exactly like what `def` creates); it's just that if you create an unnamed object in the middle of an expression, it's much harder to debug or inspect.

Comment: I have tried both methods but unfortunately neither are able to be pickled (pickleable?) by shelve.

Comment: `def` should be pickleable. `def myobj_withparam(): return myobj(param1); d = defaultdict(myobj_withparam)`